# Tesseract OCR: get coords of text and improve quality of a video frame for final OCR

Tags: php, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract OCR for text recognizing of video frames.

I wrote a program that use `ffmpeg` to get all the main frames of the video, and crop them (with static values) for center the text (it clould be, for example, subtitles).

I also use `ImageMagick` and `TextCleaner` scripts and they improve OCR's quality like a magic!

Anyway, sometimes I've got not so good video quality, or video size is a bit small, or crop not center text (becaus values are staitc), and OCR results are very bad.

My question is: How can I detect right position of the text in the for a perfetct crop?
This should improve quality of OCR and get better results.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add (links to) two samples of your frames: one "good", one "bad" (which needs detection of text position)?

Comment: Hi, the text positions are not the same: for example in this [frame](http://s7.postimg.org/5x7w6sf3v/double.jpg) text is up and down, and the resolution isn't good. Otherwise in that other [frame](http://s7.postimg.org/atbiyhf97/big.jpg) resolution is bigger and it works better. Another small exaple you can find in this other [frame](http://s7.postimg.org/inc4jvn23/small.jpg). Thank you!

Comment: It would be an important detail if the text is always in a colored box. If the box is always blueish even more.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to play with *edge detection*, and maybe combine with your other methods. Like this (purely edge detecting):

```
convert            \
  big.jpg          \
  \(               \
      big.jpg -colorspace gray -edge 8 -negate \
  \)               \
 +append           \
 -resize 50%       \
  big-edge-8.png
```

or:

```
convert            \
  big.jpg          \
  \(               \
      big.jpg -colorspace gray -edge 25 -negate \
  \)               \
 +append           \
 -resize 50%       \
  big-edge-25.png
```

Here are the two results:

[image: big-edge-8.png]

[image: big-edge-25.png]

Another option is to reduce the number of colors, apply contrast-stretching and (optionally) a threshold:

```
convert                 \
   big.jpg              \
  -colors 400           \
  -contrast-stretch 25% \
   colors-400-contraststretch-25.png

convert                 \
   big.jpg              \
  -colors 400           \
  -contrast-stretch 25% \
  -threshold 50%        \
   colors-400-contraststretch-25-threshold-50.png
```

[image: colors-400-contraststretch-25+threshold-50.png]

### Update: 'canny' edge detection

You may want to also play with `-canny`. It implents the *'canny'* edge detection algorithm and is present in ImageMagick since version 6.8.9-0. Combine it with `-contrast-stretch` and `-colorspace gray`:

```
convert big.jpg         \
  -colorspace gray      \
  -contrast-stretch 45% \
  -canny 0x1+10%+30%    \
   canny1.png

convert big.jpg         \
  -colorspace gray      \
  -contrast-stretch 45% \
  -canny 0x2+10%+30%    \
   canny2.png
```

[image: canny1+2.png]

Comment: I tried you suggestions, this methods dindn't improve my results, but I didn't know about it, +1! thank you very much, I will make some test with it.